# Expectation of maximum

Tags: probability, expectation

Assume $X_i,Y_i,Z_i,i=1,2,3,...,m$ are normal random variables with the mean of zero and different variances. also $T_i=X_i+Y_iZ_i,i=1,2,3,...,m$ where $T_i$ are probably correlated. Then I would like to know

$$
E(max_{i=1,2,3,...,m}|X_i+Y_iZ_i|)\overset{?}{\leq} E(max_{i=1,2,3,...,m}|X_i|)+E(max_{i=1,2,3,...,m}|Y_iZ_i|)
$$

Thanks.

Comment: maximum with respect to what? Sample? Please be more specific.

Comment: Dear @AlexanderVigodner thank you for mentioning the point. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

we can prove it in this way:
$$
E(max_{i=1,2,3,...,m}|X_i+Y_iZ_i|) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}max_{i=1,2,3,...,m}|X_i+Y_iZ_i|f(x,y,z)dxdydz\\
\leq
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}max_{i=1,2,3,...,m}|X_i|f(x)dx+
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}max_{i=1,2,3,...,m}|Y_iZ_i|f(y,z)dydz\\
=
E(max_{i=1,2,3,...,m}|X_i|)+E(max_{i=1,2,3,...,m}|Y_iZ_i|)\\
$$